# How to use gnutls in android studio

Tags: android, c, gnutls

I'm trying to use `gnutls` to encrypt communications.

I downloaded `gnutls` using `brew install gnutls` and placed the `.h` file in the `include` directory into my project.

Now I try to use the function from the header I `include`, but I get an error.

```
error: undefined reference to 'gnutls_hash_fast'
error: undefined reference to 'gnutls_hash_get_len'
...
```

Below is `crypto.h` from `gnutls`.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 *
 * Author: Nikos Mavrogiannopoulos
 *
 * This file is part of GnuTLS.
 *
 * The GnuTLS is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
 * the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
 * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
 *
 */

#ifndef GNUTLS_CRYPTO_H
#define GNUTLS_CRYPTO_H

#include "gnutls.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct api_cipher_hd_st *gnutls_cipher_hd_t;

int gnutls_cipher_init(gnutls_cipher_hd_t *handle,
               gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t cipher,
               const gnutls_datum_t *key, const gnutls_datum_t *iv);
int gnutls_cipher_encrypt(const gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, void *text,
              size_t textlen);
int gnutls_cipher_decrypt(const gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, void *ciphertext,
              size_t ciphertextlen);
int gnutls_cipher_decrypt2(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, const void *ciphertext,
               size_t ciphertextlen, void *text, size_t textlen);
int gnutls_cipher_encrypt2(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, const void *text,
               size_t textlen, void *ciphertext,
               size_t ciphertextlen);

/**
 * gnutls_cipher_flags_t:
 * @GNUTLS_CIPHER_PADDING_PKCS7: Flag to indicate PKCS#7 padding
 *
 * Enumeration of flags to control block cipher padding, used by
 * gnutls_cipher_encrypt3() and gnutls_cipher_decrypt3().
 *
 * Since: 3.7.7
 */
typedef enum gnutls_cipher_flags_t {
    GNUTLS_CIPHER_PADDING_PKCS7 = 1
} gnutls_cipher_flags_t;

int gnutls_cipher_encrypt3(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, const void *ptext,
               size_t ptext_len, void *ctext, size_t *ctext_len,
               unsigned flags);
int gnutls_cipher_decrypt3(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, const void *ctext,
               size_t ctext_len, void *ptext, size_t *ptext_len,
               unsigned flags);

void gnutls_cipher_set_iv(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, void *iv, size_t ivlen);

int gnutls_cipher_tag(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, void *tag, size_t tag_size);
int gnutls_cipher_add_auth(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle, const void *text,
               size_t text_size);

void gnutls_cipher_deinit(gnutls_cipher_hd_t handle);
unsigned gnutls_cipher_get_block_size(gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t algorithm)
    __GNUTLS_CONST__;
unsigned
gnutls_cipher_get_iv_size(gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t algorithm) __GNUTLS_CONST__;
unsigned gnutls_cipher_get_tag_size(gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t algorithm)
    __GNUTLS_CONST__;

/* AEAD API
 */
typedef struct api_aead_cipher_hd_st *gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t;

int gnutls_aead_cipher_init(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t *handle,
                gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t cipher,
                const gnutls_datum_t *key);

int gnutls_aead_cipher_set_key(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t handle,
                   const gnutls_datum_t *key);

int gnutls_aead_cipher_decrypt(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t handle,
                   const void *nonce, size_t nonce_len,
                   const void *auth, size_t auth_len,
                   size_t tag_size, const void *ctext,
                   size_t ctext_len, void *ptext,
                   size_t *ptext_len);
int gnutls_aead_cipher_encrypt(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t handle,
                   const void *nonce, size_t nonce_len,
                   const void *auth, size_t auth_len,
                   size_t tag_size, const void *ptext,
                   size_t ptext_len, void *ctext,
                   size_t *ctext_len);

int gnutls_aead_cipher_encryptv(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t handle,
                const void *nonce, size_t nonce_len,
                const giovec_t *auth_iov, int auth_iovcnt,
                size_t tag_size, const giovec_t *iov,
                int iovcnt, void *ctext, size_t *ctext_len);

int gnutls_aead_cipher_encryptv2(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t handle,
                 const void *nonce, size_t nonce_len,
                 const giovec_t *auth_iov, int auth_iovcnt,
                 const giovec_t *iov, int iovcnt, void *tag,
                 size_t *tag_size);

int gnutls_aead_cipher_decryptv2(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t handle,
                 const void *nonce, size_t nonce_len,
                 const giovec_t *auth_iov, int auth_iovcnt,
                 const giovec_t *iov, int iovcnt, void *tag,
                 size_t tag_size);

void gnutls_aead_cipher_deinit(gnutls_aead_cipher_hd_t handle);

/* Hash - MAC API */

typedef struct hash_hd_st *gnutls_hash_hd_t;
typedef struct hmac_hd_st *gnutls_hmac_hd_t;

size_t
gnutls_mac_get_nonce_size(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t algorithm) __GNUTLS_CONST__;
int gnutls_hmac_init(gnutls_hmac_hd_t *dig, gnutls_mac_algorithm_t algorithm,
             const void *key, size_t keylen);
void gnutls_hmac_set_nonce(gnutls_hmac_hd_t handle, const void *nonce,
               size_t nonce_len);
int gnutls_hmac(gnutls_hmac_hd_t handle, const void *text, size_t textlen);
void gnutls_hmac_output(gnutls_hmac_hd_t handle, void *digest);
void gnutls_hmac_deinit(gnutls_hmac_hd_t handle, void *digest);
unsigned gnutls_hmac_get_len(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t algorithm) __GNUTLS_CONST__;
unsigned
gnutls_hmac_get_key_size(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t algorithm) __GNUTLS_CONST__;
int gnutls_hmac_fast(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t algorithm, const void *key,
             size_t keylen, const void *text, size_t textlen,
             void *digest);
gnutls_hmac_hd_t gnutls_hmac_copy(gnutls_hmac_hd_t handle);

int gnutls_hash_init(gnutls_hash_hd_t *dig,
             gnutls_digest_algorithm_t algorithm);
int gnutls_hash(gnutls_hash_hd_t handle, const void *text, size_t textlen);
void gnutls_hash_output(gnutls_hash_hd_t handle, void *digest);
void gnutls_hash_deinit(gnutls_hash_hd_t handle, void *digest);
unsigned
gnutls_hash_get_len(gnutls_digest_algorithm_t algorithm) __GNUTLS_CONST__;
int gnutls_hash_fast(gnutls_digest_algorithm_t algorithm, const void *text,
             size_t textlen, void *digest);
gnutls_hash_hd_t gnutls_hash_copy(gnutls_hash_hd_t handle);

/* KDF API */

int gnutls_hkdf_extract(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t mac, const gnutls_datum_t *key,
            const gnutls_datum_t *salt, void *output);

int gnutls_hkdf_expand(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t mac, const gnutls_datum_t *key,
               const gnutls_datum_t *info, void *output, size_t length);

int gnutls_pbkdf2(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t mac, const gnutls_datum_t *key,
          const gnutls_datum_t *salt, unsigned iter_count, void *output,
          size_t length);

/* register ciphers */

/**
 * gnutls_rnd_level_t:
 * @GNUTLS_RND_NONCE: Non-predictable random number.  Fatal in parts
 *   of session if broken, i.e., vulnerable to statistical analysis.
 * @GNUTLS_RND_RANDOM: Pseudo-random cryptographic random number.
 *   Fatal in session if broken. Example use: temporal keys.
 * @GNUTLS_RND_KEY: Fatal in many sessions if broken. Example use:
 *   Long-term keys.
 *
 * Enumeration of random quality levels.
 */
typedef enum gnutls_rnd_level {
    GNUTLS_RND_NONCE = 0,
    GNUTLS_RND_RANDOM = 1,
    GNUTLS_RND_KEY = 2
} gnutls_rnd_level_t;

int gnutls_rnd(gnutls_rnd_level_t level, void *data, size_t len);

void gnutls_rnd_refresh(void);

/* API to override ciphers and MAC algorithms 
 */

typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_init_func)(gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t, void **ctx,
                       int enc);
typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_setkey_func)(void *ctx, const void *key,
                     size_t keysize);
/* old style ciphers */
typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_setiv_func)(void *ctx, const void *iv,
                    size_t ivsize);
typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_getiv_func)(void *ctx, void *iv, size_t ivsize);
typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_encrypt_func)(void *ctx, const void *plain,
                      size_t plainsize, void *encr,
                      size_t encrsize);
typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_decrypt_func)(void *ctx, const void *encr,
                      size_t encrsize, void *plain,
                      size_t plainsize);

/* aead ciphers */
typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_auth_func)(void *ctx, const void *data,
                       size_t datasize);
typedef void (*gnutls_cipher_tag_func)(void *ctx, void *tag, size_t tagsize);

typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_aead_encrypt_func)(
    void *ctx, const void *nonce, size_t noncesize, const void *auth,
    size_t authsize, size_t tag_size, const void *plain, size_t plainsize,
    void *encr, size_t encrsize);
typedef int (*gnutls_cipher_aead_decrypt_func)(
    void *ctx, const void *nonce, size_t noncesize, const void *auth,
    size_t authsize, size_t tag_size, const void *encr, size_t encrsize,
    void *plain, size_t plainsize);
typedef void (*gnutls_cipher_deinit_func)(void *ctx);

int gnutls_crypto_register_cipher(
    gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t algorithm, int priority,
    gnutls_cipher_init_func init, gnutls_cipher_setkey_func setkey,
    gnutls_cipher_setiv_func setiv, gnutls_cipher_encrypt_func encrypt,
    gnutls_cipher_decrypt_func decrypt,
    gnutls_cipher_deinit_func deinit) _GNUTLS_GCC_ATTR_DEPRECATED;

int gnutls_crypto_register_aead_cipher(
    gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t algorithm, int priority,
    gnutls_cipher_init_func init, gnutls_cipher_setkey_func setkey,
    gnutls_cipher_aead_encrypt_func aead_encrypt,
    gnutls_cipher_aead_decrypt_func aead_decrypt,
    gnutls_cipher_deinit_func deinit) _GNUTLS_GCC_ATTR_DEPRECATED;

typedef int (*gnutls_mac_init_func)(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t, void **ctx);
typedef int (*gnutls_mac_setkey_func)(void *ctx, const void *key,
                      size_t keysize);
typedef int (*gnutls_mac_setnonce_func)(void *ctx, const void *nonce,
                    size_t noncesize);
typedef int (*gnutls_mac_hash_func)(void *ctx, const void *text,
                    size_t textsize);
typedef int (*gnutls_mac_output_func)(void *src_ctx, void *digest,
                      size_t digestsize);
typedef void (*gnutls_mac_deinit_func)(void *ctx);
typedef int (*gnutls_mac_fast_func)(gnutls_mac_algorithm_t, const void *nonce,
                    size_t nonce_size, const void *key,
                    size_t keysize, const void *text,
                    size_t textsize, void *digest);
typedef void *(*gnutls_mac_copy_func)(const void *ctx);

int gnutls_crypto_register_mac(
    gnutls_mac_algorithm_t mac, int priority, gnutls_mac_init_func init,
    gnutls_mac_setkey_func setkey, gnutls_mac_setnonce_func setnonce,
    gnutls_mac_hash_func hash, gnutls_mac_output_func output,
    gnutls_mac_deinit_func deinit,
    gnutls_mac_fast_func hash_fast) _GNUTLS_GCC_ATTR_DEPRECATED;

typedef int (*gnutls_digest_init_func)(gnutls_digest_algorithm_t, void **ctx);
typedef int (*gnutls_digest_hash_func)(void *ctx, const void *text,
                       size_t textsize);
typedef int (*gnutls_digest_output_func)(void *src_ctx, void *digest,
                     size_t digestsize);
typedef void (*gnutls_digest_deinit_func)(void *ctx);
typedef int (*gnutls_digest_fast_func)(gnutls_digest_algorithm_t,
                       const void *text, size_t textsize,
                       void *digest);
typedef void *(*gnutls_digest_copy_func)(const void *ctx);

int gnutls_crypto_register_digest(
    gnutls_digest_algorithm_t digest, int priority,
    gnutls_digest_init_func init, gnutls_digest_hash_func hash,
    gnutls_digest_output_func output, gnutls_digest_deinit_func deinit,
    gnutls_digest_fast_func hash_fast) _GNUTLS_GCC_ATTR_DEPRECATED;

/* RSA-PKCS#1 1.5 helper functions */
int gnutls_encode_ber_digest_info(gnutls_digest_algorithm_t hash,
                  const gnutls_datum_t *digest,
                  gnutls_datum_t *output);

int gnutls_decode_ber_digest_info(const gnutls_datum_t *info,
                  gnutls_digest_algorithm_t *hash,
                  unsigned char *digest,
                  unsigned int *digest_size);

int gnutls_decode_rs_value(const gnutls_datum_t *sig_value, gnutls_datum_t *r,
               gnutls_datum_t *s);
int gnutls_encode_rs_value(gnutls_datum_t *sig_value, const gnutls_datum_t *r,
               const gnutls_datum_t *s);

int gnutls_encode_gost_rs_value(gnutls_datum_t *sig_value,
                const gnutls_datum_t *r,
                const gnutls_datum_t *s);
int gnutls_decode_gost_rs_value(const gnutls_datum_t *sig_value,
                gnutls_datum_t *r, gnutls_datum_t *s);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* GNUTLS_CRYPTO_H */
```

I think I need another task to use `gnutls`, but I don't know what it is. Do you know the solution??

Comment: The header files only tell the compiler that some functions exist, but the linker will not be able to find them unless you tell the linker in the linker search path where the gnutls library files are located. Check the NDK linker settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is only a `header` file in my `gnutls` path. Can you explain how to link to NDK??

Comment: Sorry I don't use NDK that way (especially not on a Mac). Anyway if you only have .h files then the installed package is useless for development. But I assume you just have not found the correct path. Search your system for gnutls files, you need files like `.a` `.la` `.so`